# How to order a list of tuples of integers in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting

Given a list of tuples of integers:

```
List[(Int, Int, Int)] =  List((2,1,3), (4,2,6),...)
```

I'd like to sort them by their third component but if two tuples have the same third component then I'd like to order them by their second component. For instance, I'd like (6,3,9) < (4,7,9). Here is what I tried:

```
     def order(k: List[(Int, Int, Int)]) = {
        var t = List[Int]()
        if (k.map(_._3) == t) {
            k.sortBy(_._2)
            t = k.map(_._3)
            k
        } else {
            k.sortBy(_._3)
            t = k.map(_._3)
            k
        }   
     }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You probably know this already, but tuples have their own Ordering -- increasing _1, increasing _2, increasing _3 -- so if you have the option of changing the order of the fields in the tuple to (c,b,a) you could just use plain old `sorted`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A rather simple and surprisingly fast approach is to use a *stable* sorting algorithm, and sort first by the first component, then by the second, then by the third.
Since you sorted last by the third component, this will be dominant. When using a stable sort, objects tied in the last component will be ordered by the previous one:

```
Sorting.stableSort(k, (x, y) => x._1 < y._1)
Sorting.stableSort(k, (x, y) => x._2 < y._2)
Sorting.stableSort(k, (x, y) => x._3 < y._3)
```

or equivalently (but probably more expensive, as it builds a sequence of keys):

```
Sorting.stableSort(k, x => x._1)
Sorting.stableSort(k, x => x._2)
Sorting.stableSort(k, x => x._3)
```

(assuming that `Seq.sortBy` is not stable.)

Alternatively (and this is the more classic and obvious approach), write a comparator (`Ordering`) that uses the third component *if different*, then the second *if different* and finally the first one. This is probably not very "scalish", but it is IMHO very clean and understandable:

```
val result = intOrdering.compare(x._3, y._3)
if (result == 0) result = intOrdering.compare(x._2, y._2)
if (result == 0) result = intOrdering.compare(x._1, y._1)
result
```

again, you can also use a key function (but this will need 2x as much memory):

```
k.sortBy(x => (x._3, x._2, x._1))
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that

```
k.sortBy(x => (x._3 , x._2))
```

does the job and returns

```
List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((2,1,3), (4,2,6), (6,3,9), (4,7,9), (6,7,11),
          (8,4,12), (10,5,15), (12,1,17), (12,6,18), (8,14,18), (6,17,19))
```

which also works for (12,6,18), (8,14,18)

Comment: For large lists, providing an `Ordering` will be faster than this `sortBy`, as this requires a transformation on each element.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide your own `Ordering[Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]]`, then just use `sorted` on the `List`. For example, here is something like the standard `Ordering` on `Tuple3`, except the sorting on the ordinates is reversed. For any `(a, b, c)`, `c` has a higher priority than `b`, and `b` has a higher priority than `a`. You didn't really mention how to handle `a`, so if you don't care about it, you can just remove the relevant lines.

```
val list = List((2,1,3), (4,2,6), (4,7,9), (6,3,9), (6,7,11), (6,17,19), (8,4,12), (8,14,18), (10,5,15), (12,1,17), (12,6,18))

implicit def t3Ordering(implicit intOrdering: Ordering[Int]) = new Ordering[Tuple3[Int, Int, Int]] {
    def compare(x: (Int, Int, Int), y: (Int, Int, Int)): Int = {
        val compare3 = intOrdering.compare(x._3, y._3)
        if (compare3 != 0) return compare3
        val compare2 = intOrdering.compare(x._2, y._2)
        if (compare2 != 0) return compare2
        val compare1 = intOrdering.compare(x._1, y._1)
        if (compare1 != 0) return compare1
        0
    }
}

scala> list.sorted
res0: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((2,1,3), (4,2,6), (6,3,9), (4,7,9), (6,7,11), (8,4,12), (10,5,15), (12,1,17), (12,6,18), (8,14,18), (6,17,19))
```

Or to more generally reverse the sorting based on `Tuple` ordinates (for `Tuple3`):

```
implicit def t3Ordering[T1, T2, T3](implicit ord1: Ordering[T1], ord2: Ordering[T2], ord3: Ordering[T3]) = 
  new Ordering[Tuple3[T1, T2, T3]] {
    def compare(x: (T1, T2, T3), y: (T1, T2, T3)): Int = {
        val compare3 = ord3.compare(x._3, y._3)
        if (compare3 != 0) return compare3
        val compare2 = ord2.compare(x._2, y._2)
        if (compare2 != 0) return compare2
        val compare1 = ord1.compare(x._1, y._1)
        if (compare1 != 0) return compare1
        0
    }
  }
```

Based on the [standard library Ordering](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L369-L380).